# Why does D in the chord progression "Cm Eb F Bb7 C D" sound correct?

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I'm writing a song in C Aeolian/Dorian (the verses are in Aeolian and the chorus is in Dorian). And I came up with a weird chord progression for the end of my chorus:

Cm Eb F Bb7 C D

My question is why does the D sound right at the end? Usually, songs end with a tonic (I, vi, etc.), but the D here, as far as I can tell is a dominant of a dominant (V/V). It's the dominant of G which is the dominant of C. Just looking at this progression, it wouldn't seem like the ending would sound resolved, but when I play it, it sounds great. Can anyone explain the theory behind this?

Comment: I'm curious just how resolved this sounds for you.  Does it sound like complete resolution, ie, no other chord in place of or following it would sound more resolved?

Comment: Also, what instrument are you playing this on?  If guitar, are you just playing barre chords, or are you using traditional voice leading?

Comment: I'm playing it on the keyboard (I use inversions to make it move around less, and I don't play the 7 on the B, that's in the melody). As for how complete the resolution sounds, it sounds good for the end of a song, though it has a bit of mystery to it, like your waiting for something, but don't know what (not as in you know where it wants to go). Sorry, I don't really know how to describe it. I'm sure there are other chords that would make it sound more resolved.

Comment: @DavidBowling: The F instead of Fm is because this is Dorian (not Aeolian). However, the C major is neither a Dorian nor an Aeolian chord which is probably why this question arose in the first place (I was writing in two modes and then used a chord that belonged in neither). This could very well be a modulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of context, the progression seems to establish Bb major as a tonic, then plane up to D.  It could continue further - try my first suggestion!   Or we could return to functional harmony and resolve the D to Gm.

A lot of music is functional, all about dominants and tonics.  A lot isn't.   And a whole other lot is a mix.  You can go mad trying to find a functional justification for an ending like Bb, C, D - but it's very popular!  Just let it be 'planing' - the same chord shape shifting up or down in pitch.   Semitone planes work as well, Bb, B, C is another popular ending (in the key of C).  Don't sweat over justifing the Bb as a functional harmony - just accept it as 'two under C' so a good starting point for a plane ride up to C.

Take in the message of the first part of this answer, and the first musical example.  Yes, it's possible to end satisfyingly on D.  But it's JUST as satisfying to carry on up to E!   In functional harmony, you KNOW when you're home.  In this freer style, free from the tyrrany of the leading-note, there's a wider choice of resting points.

[image]

Comment: In other words, the C chord is acting as a passing chord between the Bb and the D: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vgdcixdlymuvomb/Ending.PNG?dl=0 Did I understand that right? So it's more about what works than about theory, I guess.

Comment: @C.Stucky I'd say that theory is there to guide you, and provide "warnings" about transitions that will sound good,  strange, or just plain horrible :-)

Comment: I don't really see how this answer provides any sort of thought process as to why ending on the D sounds resolved.  The philosophy of not needing to worry about naming every little thing in music theory terms is very valuable but it's not much of an answer to a theory question.

Comment: @C.Stucky Theory is essentially trying to describe what is happening and explain why it sounds good.  The distinction I would make is not so much that the theory doesn't matter because it works but that some theory can't be used to describe everything.  In this case, thinking of things in terms of Functional harmony, ie, dominants resolving to tonics, would not really provide the theory answer you're looking for.

Comment: So what would you do, @Basstickler?  Tear the progression apart until you found some convoluted way to describe each chord as a dominant of the next?  It could be done.  I've seen people obsessed with functional harmony do it...

Comment: @Basstickler When I said "it's more about what works than about theory", I was referring to this specific case. The theory I've heard so far does not completely explain this case. I'm all for theory when it helps me find good progressions (I've got an app on my computer that has a large map of chords and where they belong, it really helps me create interesting progressions that sound nice). I'm also writing counterpoint (using all the rules that people have made using theory) for this same song. I'm not against theory in general, it just doesn't help explain this situation.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - No, my point was that there are other types of theory than Functional Harmony, which can be valuable tools.  This isn't to say that you MUST describe everything in terms of theory, as that's not really necessary, since if it sounds good, it sounds good.  The only real reason I mention it here is that the OP was asking for a theoretical way of understanding why the D sounds resolved.  As much as likely Planing describes what they're doing, it doesn't really provide a reason why that chord feels resolved.

Comment: @C.Stucky - That's where I would disagree.  You're probably referring to Functional Harmony.  You can always describe things in terms of theory.  It's not always valuable to everyone but it's there.  My initial thoughts on this were along the lines of voice leading being the primary reason it sounds more resolved than would be expected.  Alternatively, the use of the Bb - C major at the end could contribute to a feeling of a modal cadence from D Aeolian, or modal interchange in a major mode of D.

Comment: @Basstickler I've been playing around with this a bit and found that an ending with G instead of D also works well (G minor works too, although it doesn't sound as good because of the C). The G ending is particularly great for returning to the verses in C Aeolian, while the D ending wants to modulate to a D Aeolian. If you're talking about what note the melody plays when you say voice-leading, it's going down from an A over the Bb, to a G over the C, to and F# over the D.

Comment: I thought Gm more appropriate because of the previous Bb chord!   But both are possible.  'Theory' can cope with either, but doesn't INSTRUCT us to choose either in particular.   I say yet again - "Theory describes, it does not command".

Comment: @C.Stucky - The melody would be a part of the voice leading but also how the chords are voiced and how the voices within those chords move.  That melody could be part of the explanation, as well as the Bb being a major 7 chord.  You have step-wise, descending motion, resolving a half step to the third of the final chord, very similar to a V7-I cadence.  So I think that voice leading is a big part of why this sounds particularly resolved.

Comment: @LaurencePayne - I entirely agree.  So my point here is that there can be a theoretical EXPLANATION outside of functional harmony.  Whether or not this is valuable to any given person is entirely subjective, just like any sort of theory.  Some people don't need any theory at all to progress as musicians, while it allows others to thrive.  In this case, a question was asked about why it sounded resolved, which I didn't think was found within your answer, even though your answer did provide valuable insight.

Comment: Explanation or just description?   Where doninants and tonics, leading notes and tritones are involved, we can maybe explain a functional explanation.  We can EXPLAIN the D - Gm ending option in the second of my musical examples.  But what can we do with the fact that Bb - C - D is a satisfactory ending, but so is Bb - C - D - E ?  I can note that planing works.  It's hard to say WHY.

Comment: Somehow I never came across the term *planing* before.  I get the principle and have encountered it and used it, but never put a name to it.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been a long time since someone posted this but I came across it by accident while doing some work online and it caught my attention.

The answer lies in the Bb7 which wants to go to Eb, you then raise the chord to a C major. This would be Bb major/ C minor/ D minor(D diminished)/ Eb major: In the key of Eb.

Instead, you have substituted from the parallel key (C major is a III of Eb or a I of C minor)

The D major would seem like it doesn't belong, but then again you have moved up from a C major and are already heading toward that implied destination (Bb C D...Eb!) but not played the Eb major, starting on the Bb7 (since it's a dominant chord) it is implied there will be an Eb to the ear.

You have then planed up and finished on the D major, again implying an Eb and its third G (which also happens to be the 4th of D). Since Cm and Eb are interchangeable as in (i>III or I>vi).

It still is relatable to the C minor tonal center of your piece while leaving the listener in an ambiguous state. Without realizing it, you have maintained that tonal center. Everything you play implies an Eb and what "doesn't fit" still retains enough of that C minor Eb major.

Even more can be said, for example, D sits between the C and the Eb being both ones IInd and the others VIIth, and "hears" the thing (oh god puns) that's, generally speaking, a Locrian based diminished chord and we substitute them all the time in music outside of jazz because they are just so unstable. So throwing a D major in there isn't at all uncommon. I'll leave it there for now. It's a wonderful Cadence, my friend.

Comment: Re: paragraph 3, C is not the III of Eb major. Rather, Eb is the III of C minor - I think you had it backwards? Or, alternatively, C is the VI for Eb major. Might want to fix that for clarity, but an excellent response nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the reality: *there are no incorrect chord changes*.

There are only varying degrees of *stylistically unconventional chord changes*.

Most likely you are taking *common practice* harmony conventions, which is what most harmony theory texts teach, which in a nutshell is the harmony style of composers like Haydn from the eighteenth century, and applying that to a pop/rock style, or whatever is your personal style.

Your chord progression doesn't really do anything to set up a tonic/dominant relationship in the *common practice* convention. So don't use that convention for analysis.

> Just looking at this progression, it wouldn't seem like the ending would sound resolved, but when I play it, it sounds great.

It doesn't sound resolved. But, that doesn't mean that it can't sound good.

"Good" is too vague for analysis. The problem is the question is based on just a chord list. In comments you hint at voice leading and interaction between accompaniment and melody, but we don't know what those details are. You should post a score.

You could handle it like this...

[image]

...using rhythm, duration to create chord relationships. By using longer durations on `F` and `D` major, we can create a relationship between two particular chords by phrasing. Harmonically we then have a *chromatic mediant* relationship between the two chords. Chromatic mediants are kind of "moody" so we now have some structure and emotional potential.

Or, I could grouping chords in pairs to structure and phrase around possible scales/tonalities...

[image]

Assuming your progression repeats, I wondered how to make sense of `D` major to `C` minor. Both chords match the `G` harmonic minor scale. The roots are separated by a whole step. I could see the other chord could be paired up with certain scales. And the tonics of the scales could be selected to make each pair a rising sequence. Then you can try giving it a melodic idea. After shifting the bar line it could be like this...

[image]

I doubt any of this is like whatever you are doing with rhythm, voicing, melody, etc. But the point is to show that a mere list of chords isn't enough to explain how something works.

> My question is why does the D sound right at the end?

I don't know what it's doing in your work. But I tried to make it work as a chromatic mediant or a `V` from `G` harmonic minor. You could try to make it work a variety of ways.